# Passing asp.net values to JavaScript function

Tags: asp.net

I need to pass the TextBox control to the JavaScript function. How do I do it

ASP.NET

```
OnClick="PassVal('<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>')"
```

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function PassVal(ctrl, e) {
            alert(ctrl);
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Ms Ajax:

```
function Blablabla(){

  var ctrl = $get('<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>');

}
```

If you are using jQuery:

```
function Blablabla(){

  var ctrl = $('#<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>');

}
```

but basically it is:

```
function Blablabla(){

  var ctrl = document.getElementById('<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you may modify the html that is output by accessing the Response.Body or similar. I'm not remembering the exact name.

you can then put a piece of script to it:

```
Response.Body += "<script type=\"text/javascript\">";
Response.Body += "    PassVal(" + myControl + "," + myE + ");"
Response.Body += "</script>"
```

hope this helped you a bit. you have to look up the name of the property, don't got any VS here currently.

regards

Answer (score 0):

This has been discussed before at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295180/whats-the-best-way-to-embed-constant-server-side-tags-inside-javascript-code).